# How to stop MPI process within the process itself (for distributed termination detection algorithm)?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am working on a C++ project with MPI that implements distributed termination detection algorithm. The termination part looks like the following:

```
MPI_Iprobe(MASTER, TERMINATION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &terminationFlag, &status); 
if (terminationFlag!=0)
{
     MPI_Recv(0, 0, MPI_INT, MASTER, TERMINATION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     //Halt the process
}
```

MPI_Iprobe looks for a message with TERMINATION tag from MASTER node (MASTER Sends the termination message when the termination condition is detected). If the message exist, the current process receives the message and stops itself.

Here, I am wondering how to gracefully stop the process once the termination message is received. I have tried MPI_Finalize(), but the program keeps generating the following error:

```
*** The MPI_Send() function was called after MPI_FINALIZE was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
```

I usually place MPI_Finalize() on the bottom of the code to make sure everything is finished before calling this function. However, because the process may stop itself during the middle of the process. I don't know if I should use MPI_Finalize().

I am using mpic++ as the compiler and mpirun to run the program.

---

Update:

As Hristo and suszterpatt pointed out, I should use `MPI_Finalize()` followed by `return 0`. This seems to solve the problem.

Comment: What happens after the call to `MPI_Finalize()`? Note that `MPI_Finalize()` doesn't actually kill the process, it just signals that the process' participation in the MPI job has finished.

Comment: Place a `return` statement or a call to `exit(2)` after the call to `MPI_Finalize()`. Note that some MPI implementations trap program exits via an `atexit(3)` handler and keep the process alive until all other processes have finalised MPI.

Comment: I used `return 0` after running `MPI_Finalize()`. It seems to work! Thank you Hristo and suszterpatt!